# Find the eigenspaces of $\;\;\pmatrix{7 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 10 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & -8}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $$ A = \pmatrix{7 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 10 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & -8},$$

Using the fact that $(A-\lambda I)v=0$, where $\lambda \in \{-9, 10, 8\},$

I have found

- The eigenspaces for $\lambda=-9$ to be the set of non-zero vectors $(\frac{1}
  {4}k,0,k)$, where k $\ne0$,
- The eigenspaces for $\lambda=8$ to be the set of non-zero vectors $(4k,0,k)$, where k $\ne0$,
- The eigenspaces for $\lambda=10$ to be the set of non-zero vectors $(0,k,0)$, where k $\ne0$.

I'm not totally sure about the last eigenspaces as in solving the inequation I obtained, $x=4/3z$ and $x=9/2z$, which is plausible if and only if, $x=z=0$.

Are these the correct eigenspaces? Is my last reasoning sound?

Comment: The last one is true.

Comment: The first one should be $(-\frac 1 4 k, 0, k)$.

Comment: As a way to check your answer, note that the eigenspaces must be orthogonal to each other since the matrix is symmetric. This is not the case for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your eigenspace for $\lambda=-9$ is wrong.

You want

$$-9\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7x+4z\\10y\\4x-8z\end{pmatrix}$$

so $y=0$, $-9x=7x+4z$ and $-9z=4x-8z$ giving $-4x=z$, therefore it should be $(-k/4,0,k)$.

Your reasoning for the other two is right.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this using Wolfram Alpha to reduce row echelon form the matrices in the form of $A-\lambda I$.

- [$\lambda=-9$](http://bit.ly/24nXWWk) gives us $(-x, 0, 4x)$. ([The reduced row echelon form of $A+9I$](http://bit.ly/1rRUqlW) shows why.)
- [$\lambda=8$](http://bit.ly/1UwzcVJ) gives us $(4x, 0, x)$.
- [$\lambda=10$](http://bit.ly/1W75TdT) gives us $(0, x, 0)$.